# Accessing function results from another Jquery

Tags: jquery

hope someone can assist with the following.

I have a function that reads image data from database and returns the object url to be displayed based on the image/file type.

```
function newFile(data) {
//example image j -> jpg image type
 if ('j'.search(imgType) >= 0)
  {
     var d = imgData;
     data = new Uint8Array(d.length / 2);
     for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i += 2)
     data[i/2] = parseInt(d.substr(i, 2), 16);
     mime_type = 'image/jpeg';
  } 
  //example image s -> svg image type
 if ('s'.search(imgType) >= 0)
  { 
    var d = imgData;
    mime_type = 'image/svg+xml';
  } 
    url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], { type: mime_type }));
}
```

How would i access this function from another file and function, using it to render other images. example if i have an jpg it does the conversion to the image. I am trying to create a preview page, and would like to use the above function instead of copying and pasting this in another on click function.

```
$('.preview').click(function(){
$.ajax({
  url: "/images.php",
  data: { id: "imageId"},
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(ids){
    {
      for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; ++i)
      {
        var k = ids[i].result[0];
        if (k.imgType = 'j')) //jpg
        {
          //go to newFile function where k.imgType = j return image blob url
          $('previewer').html("<img src="'url'">");
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

});

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code. Also, the brackets aren't balanced.

Comment: `'j'.search(imgType)` doesn't make much sense. Did you mean `imgType.search(/j/)`?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

Your code was a mess by the way. Missing brackets all over the place.

Also if there is more than one image (you DO loop) then you need to append

I cannot guarantee the code below works, but it is closer than it were

```js
const mimeTypes = {
  'j': 'image/jpeg',
  's': 'image/svg+xml'
}
// not tested but cleaned up
function newFile(imgData, imgType) {
  const data = new Uint8Array(imgData.length / 2);
  for (let i = 0; i < imgData.length; i += 2) {
    data[i / 2] = parseInt(imgData.substr(i, 2), 16);
  }
  return window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], {
    type: mimeTypes[imgType]
  }));
}

$('.preview').on("click", function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/images.php",
    data: {
      id: "imageId"
    },
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(ids) {
      for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; ++i) {
        const k = ids[i].result[0];
        $('previewer').append('<img src="data:' + mimeTypes[k.imgType] + ';' + newFile(k.imgData, k.imgType + '">')
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The function should end with `return url;`.

Then you can call it from the AJAX success function.

```
$('previewer').html(`<img src='" + newFile(k) + "'>");
```

Comment: I think there is a bit more to it than that. Please see my answer for what I mean

Comment: I was ignoring all the messed up code, and assuming that would be fixed independently.

Comment: Also they need to append or they will only see the last image

Comment: hi @Barmar code was fixed, it was taken from a long file and i only wanted to show code i was trying to use.